# How to tell the IDE a method returns a list containing only a specific type of Objects in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm using the PyCharm Community Edition on development.

I know I can use python docstrings to set a return with :rtype:.

But how can I tell that a method returns a list with specific objects type and then be able to use autocomplete after that.

```
class MyObject:
    def method_1(self):
        do_something()
    def method_2(self):
        do_something()

class ReturnListOfObjects:
    def return_list_of_MyObjects():
    """
    :rtype: (here I usually put just list, but can not use autocomplete after)
    """
```

Comment: you can try `[MyObject]` to say that is a list of MyObject or saying it more verbose like: return a list of MyObject

Comment: What do you want? To explain in the doc string the type of return your method will have (what I understand from the body fo your post) or you want to return a list from the method (what I understand from the title)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link - https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#d314357e162, it should be:

```
list[MyObject]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @AbuAshrafMasnun!
I discovered that I can also use: list of _MyObject_